# Does my tunneling question belong here or on SU?

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question, super-user

I've just asked this:

[How do corkscrew, proxytunnel and httptunnel set tunnels up?](https://serverfault.com/q/990476/113898)

but on second though, I'm not sure whether it belongs on SF or on SU. On one hand, it's about managing network traffic; and firewalls are definitely on-topic. But maybe tunneling is too "userish"... what say you?

Answer (score 2):

At first look I don't see it off-topic, but I'am not a linux admin. I'am more on the dark side as a Windows's admin. To note 'how something work' is sometime closed as learning recommendation, depending on how you wrote your question.

For your question itself as I dont know much those tools I checked and proxytunnel last update seem in 2008 and httptunnel in 2010. It picked my interest on the why the tool are so old and still used, I started to dig what it do, and some cases seem to bypass a local firewall or such network restriction.

Your question is fine at the moment as you don't state the why you are dooing so, as like you told it can be to manage network traffic, but yes it could land into SU's territory depending on the why you use the tool(s). If it's in exemple to bypass your enterprise router/firewall, as at that point you fall as an enduser of your netadmin and you try to bypass his rules.